# align-self:flex-end and margin-bottom: xpx not working as expected in Safari and iOS devices

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

I'm having some issues with iOS ignoring a combo of `align-self:flex-end` and `margin-bottom: 8px`.

On Android devices, various Windows versions with Chrome and Firefox, and Chrome on macOS, `#totalImg` is displayed as I'd expect it to be - bottom right corner, slightly raised.

On Safri for macOS and Safari and Chrome for iOS, `#totalImg` is glued to the bottom.

See the following image for current behaviour:

[image]

I'm aware that I could get consistent cross-browser behaviour by applying `bottom: 8px`, but that seems to be working just in my test case, and fails in production, depending on the screen width of Android or iOS devices. For example, on Chrome for Android, with `bottom: 8px`, `#totalImages` can end up in the middle of its parent `div`, or well below it.

```css
    .image.big.j_launch {
      display: flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
    }
    .image.big {
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      max-width: 320px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      float: none;
      position: relative;
    }
    #totalImg {
      display: block;
      height: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      right: 11px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
      padding: 2px 6px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      color: white;
      font-size: 11px;
      text-align: center;
      align-self: flex-end;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="image big j_launch" data-index="0">
      <div id="totalImg"><span>1 / 18</span></div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/320x240">
    </div>
```

How can I get a consistent crossbrowser solution, which would place `#totalImg` as it's currently placed in the first image? Is there a reason for Safari (and iOS in general) to ignore what seems to be working on other platforms / browsers?

Looking at the document inspector in Safari, I can see that the margin is applied - there's an orange rectangle below `#totalImg`, which keeps growing / extending itself downwards, when I'm changing the `margin-bottom` value in the stylesheet inspector. It's just not being applied ***visually*** as I'd expect it to be.

Comment: I've had similar issues with Safari ignoring widely used CSS properties unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is **a** solution, is not the best solution, and I'd recommend against it, even though it works.

First, a little bit of JavaScript is needed (as seen on [this link](https://codepen.io/samiah/pen/NgQKMb)).

```
var b = document.documentElement;
b.setAttribute('data-useragent',  navigator.userAgent);
b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform );
b.className += ((!!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window))?' touch':'');
```

What this block does is that it adds two data attributes to the document itself (and a `touch` class if it's a handheld device). In my case - iPhone and Mac - `data-platform` had values of `iPhone` and `MacIntel`, respectively. `classname` and `data-useragent` are unnecessary in this context, but were not removed from the original code for illustrative purposes.

Next, add some new rules to CSS.

```
html[data-platform*='Mac'] #totalImg,
html[data-platform*='iPhone'] #totalImg {
  bottom: 8px !important;
  margin-bottom: unset !important;
}
```

This relies on partial macthings by the platform, and adjusts the rules accordingly - since `bottom` was recognized and applied on `*OS` devices, and `margin-bottom` was not, the rules are changed.

The reason I dislike this is that looks like a [Rube Goldberg machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine), and it's overly complicated for something that should've been solved in CSS alone.

Not to mention that it relies on a deprecated / obsolete feature.